# AutoComplete: Only allow selected valued from suggested list

Tags: javascript, php

I have an autocomplete script which suggest a list of tags that can be chosen from our database. The user can also type a new one even if it's not suggested.

I would only like to let the user choose a suggested value from the list. This is our code:

```
<input id="tokenfield" class="with-border" type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Ejemplo: PHP, Google Adwords, Traducción, etc.">
                                        

<script type="text/javascript">
    var action = "skill_tag_search";

  $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
      
    autocomplete: {
      source: function (request, response) {
          jQuery.get(ajaxurl, {
              action: action, query: request.term
          }, function (data) {

              data = $.parseJSON(data);
              response(data);
          });
      },
      delay: 100
    },
    showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the change event of jQuery autocomplete?
[https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#:~:text=Events-,change,-(%20event%2C%20ui%20)](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#:%7E:text=Events-,change,-(%20event%2C%20ui%20))

Last time I solved it doing something like this.

```
$('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
autocomplete: {
  source: function (request, response) {
      jQuery.get(ajaxurl, {
          action: action, query: request.term
      }, function (data) {

          data = $.parseJSON(data);
          response(data);
      });
  },
  delay: 100,
  change: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui) {
            $(tokenfield).val(//Clear the autocomplete field);
        } else {
            $(tokenfield).val(//Set value to the autocomplete field);
        }
      }
    },
  showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
});
```